# jquery draggable into empty list

Tags: jquery, draggable

I am using this example from jquery ui: http://jsbin.com/odiqi3

I have deliberately made sortable list empty in the example below because I want to start dropping into an empty list:

http://jsbin.com/odiqi3/163

Is there a way to do this?

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
 revert: true
});
$("#draggable").draggable({
  connectToSortable: '#sortable1',
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: 'invalid'
});
$("ul, li").disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't drag into an empty list is because it has a height of 0 (since there are no list items in it).  So if you specify a height in the CSS, like so:

```
#sortable1 {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Then you can drag into the empty list.  Here's the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/odiqi3/165).

Answer (score 1):

You have to give

```
#sortable1 {
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer if you're working with a dynamic list. Setting a definitive height for a box only ensures the box remains the same height regardless of how many items it has in it. Thanks for the help